# Extract info using awk

Tags: awk

My input is:

```
group;|line1_1|line2_2|line3_3
```

I want to extract the inforamtion line1,line2,line3 as below output:
line1,line2,line3

I have tried by using the following command but not executable:

```
LINE="group;|line1_1|line2_2|line3_3"; echo $LINE | awk -F ";" '{print $2}' | awk -F "|" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i){print $i | system("cut -d _ -f1")}}'
```

Comment: Not clear, please mention sample clear input and expected sample output in code tags and let us know then.

Comment: My input is exactly the same as i posted. And my expected output is: line1,line2,line3. (only the linex information)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that your actual Input_file is same as shown samples. Could you please try following.

```
awk -F'|' '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){sub(/_.*/,"",$i);val=val?val OFS $i:$i};print val;val=""}'  OFS=","  Input_file
```

***2nd Solution:*** Only using `sub` and `gsub` of `awk` here.

```
awk '{sub(/^[^|]*\|/,"");gsub(/_[0-9]\|/,",");sub(/_[0-9]$/,"")} 1' Input_file
OR
awk '{gsub(/^[^|]*\||_[0-9]$/,"");gsub(/_[0-9]\|/,",")} 1' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
line1,line2,line3
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code now.

```
awk -F'|' '                    ##Setting field separator as | here for all lines.
{                              ##Starting block here.
  for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){          ##Starting for loop starting form i=2 to till value of NF here.
    sub(/_.*/,"",$i)           ##Using sub for substitution from _ to till everything with NULL in value of $i.
    val=val?val OFS $i:$i      ##Creating variable val and concatenate its own value if it is having NON ZERO value else save in it for 1st time.
  }                            ##Close for loop block here.
  print val                    ##Printing value of val here.
  val=""                       ##Nullifying value of variable val here.
}'  OFS=","  Input_file        ##Setting value of OFS to comma here and mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your help. Could you please explain more detail for the part val=val?val OFS $i:$i};print val;val="". I dont really understand this part.

Comment: @NamTran, will add explanation too in few mins, glad that it helped you.

Comment: @NamTran, please check explanation and let me know if you have any doubts on it too.

Comment: really appreciate your kind help.